# Convert inline image tags like [image:123:title:size] into HTML img tags

Tags: php, html, arrays, image, preg-match-all

I am looking for help with regular expression $pattern to convert inline image tags like [image:123:title:size] into HTML img tags.

here is the code:

```
//[image:ID:caption:size]
$content = '[image:38:title:800x900]';

preg_match_all( '/\[image:(\d+)(:?)([^\]]*)\]/i', $content, $images );

        if( !empty( $images[0] ) )
        {   // There are image inline tags in the content
            foreach( $images[0] as $i => $tag )
            {

            $link_ID = (int)$images[1][$i];
            $caption = empty( $images[2][$i] ) ? '#' : $images[3][$i];
            $size = empty( $images[4][$i] ) ? '#' : $images[5][$i];

            }
            echo '<br />';
            echo 'ID: '.$link_ID.'<br />';
            echo 'Tag: '.$caption.'<br />';
            echo 'size: '.$size.'<br />';
        }
```

which outputs:

image id: 12

Title: caption:size

size: #

but should output this:

image id: 12

Title: caption

size: size

this---> /[image:(\d+)(:?)([^]]*)]/i

does not work

Any help would be great!

Comment: whats adding that sort of image 'tag' ??

Comment: it's part of other code. I need the 3 variables to convert further.

Comment: it's a function that extracts content from a post and looks for that pattern and then converts it into an image tag.

Comment: For the example you've given (`[image:38:title:800x900]`), what would a processed `<img/>` look like? `<img src="38.jpg" alt="title" width=800 height=900>`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you're looking for? I'm assuming you were doing inline parsing, so preg_replace, might do a better job. I'm not sure the exact details of what you're trying to do though.

```
<?php

$content = 'Check out my awesome [image:38:title:800x900], but not as good as my other [image:20:thumbnail:200x200]';

$parsed_content = preg_replace( '/\[image:(\d+):([^\:]+):(\d+)x(\d+)\]/i', '<img src=\'$1.jpg\' alt=\'$2\' width=$3 height=$4>', $content);

echo "Before: {$content}\n";
echo "After: {$parsed_content}\n";
```

Outputs:

> Before: Check out my awesome `[image:38:title:800x900]`, but not as good
>   as my other `[image:20:thumbnail:200x200]`
>
> After: Check out my awesome
>   `<img src='38.jpg' alt='title' width=800 height=900>`, but not as good
>   as my other `<img src='20.jpg' alt='thumbnail' width=200 height=200>`

EDIT:

```
<?php
$content = '[image:38:title:800x900]';

preg_match_all( '/\[image:(?<id>\d+):(?<caption>[^:]+):(?<size>[\dx]+)/i', $content, $images );

        if( !empty( $images[0] ) )
        {   // There are image inline tags in the content
            foreach( $images[0] as $i => $tag )
            {

            $link_ID = (int)$images['id'][$i];
            $caption = empty( $images['caption'][$i] ) ? '#' : $images['caption'][$i];
            $size = empty( $images['size'][$i] ) ? '#' : $images['size'][$i];

            }
            echo '<br />' . "\n";
            echo 'ID: '.$link_ID.'<br />' . "\n";
            echo 'Tag: '.$caption.'<br />' . "\n";
            echo 'size: '.$size.'<br />' . "\n";
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it is not what I am looking for.

I simply want the correct expression to split it by ":"

/\[image:(\d+):([^\:]+):(\d+)x(\d+)\]/i

so that it outputs:

image id: 12

Title: caption

size: size

instead of 



image id: 12

Title: caption:size

size: #

Comment: I've updated the answer with your original code, which now does what I think you're after.

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED!

```
$content = '[image:12:caption:size]';
preg_match_all( '/\[image:(\d+)(:?)(.*)(:)([^\]]*)\]/i', $content, $images );

        if( !empty( $images[0] ) )
        {   // There are image inline tags in the content
            foreach( $images[0] as $i => $tag )
            {

                $link_ID = (int)$images[1][$i];
                $caption = empty( $images[2][$i] ) ? '#' : $images[3][$i];
                $size = empty( $images[4][$i] ) ? '#' : $images[5][$i];
                print_r($images);
            }
            echo '<br />';
            echo 'ID: '.$link_ID.'<br />';
            echo 'Title: '.$caption.'<br />';
            echo 'Dimensions: '.$size.'<br />';
        }
```

**replaced:**

```
/\[image:(\d+)(:?)([^\]]*)\]/i
```

**with:**

```
/\[image:(\d+)(:?)(.*)(:)([^\]]*)\]/i
```

**Thank You!**